# Numpy array of tuples to PIL image

Tags: python, arrays, image, numpy, python-imaging-library

I currently have a numpy array or RBG tuples that I want to convert to a PIL image and save. Currently I'm doing the following: `final = Image.fromarray(im_arr, mode='RGB')`. Here `im_arr` is the numpy array of tuples in the form `(R, G, B)`. It seems to end up keeping the tuples separate when it creates the image as shown below.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try using these functions:

```
import numpy
import Image

def PIL2array(img):
    return numpy.array(img.getdata(),
                    numpy.uint8).reshape(img.size[1], img.size[0], 3)

def array2PIL(arr, size):
    mode = 'RGBA'
    arr = arr.reshape(arr.shape[0]*arr.shape[1], arr.shape[2])
    if len(arr[0]) == 3:
        arr = numpy.c_[arr, 255*numpy.ones((len(arr),1), numpy.uint8)]
    return Image.frombuffer(mode, size, arr.tostring(), 'raw', mode, 0, 1)

def main():
    img = loadImage('foo.jpg')
    arr = PIL2array(img)
    img2 = array2PIL(arr, img.size)
    img2.save('out.jpg')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Credit: http://code.activestate.com/recipes/577591-conversion-of-pil-image-and-numpy-array/

Additional Information: http://www.imagexd.org/tutorial/lessons/0_images_are_arrays.html

In case it doesn't work, maybe your array does not have the appropriate shape.

Answer (score 0):

If your array is an array of form width, height and filled with tuples, this code converts it to an array of arrays, which can be read by Image.fromarray.

```
import numpy as np
from PIL import Image


arr = np.array(
    [
        [(178, 158, 165), (185, 196, 191), (207, 222, 226)],
        [(202, 184, 176), (68, 58, 66), (69, 57, 60)],
        [(194, 158, 179), (109, 119, 116), (70, 64, 57)]
    ]
)           # a small example array

shape = arr.shape
new_arr = np.empty((shape[0], shape[1], 3), dtype=np.uint8)
for y, row in enumerate(arr):
    for x, color in enumerate(row):
        new_arr[y, x] = np.array(color)

Image.fromarray(new_arr, "RGB").show()
```

This is probably slow for larger images compared to the other answer, but that one didn't work for me.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your integers are uint8: `Image.fromarray(im_arr.astype(np.uint8), "RGB")` and your array shape is `(height, width, channels)`:

```py
from PIL import Image
import numpy as np


im = Image.new("RGB", (2, 1))
im.putpixel((0, 0), (255, 0, 0))
im.putpixel((1, 0), (0, 255, 0))

a = np.array(im)
print("Good:", a.shape, a, a.dtype)
# (1, 2, 3) [[[255 0 0] [0 255 0]]] uint8
print("See?")
Image.fromarray(a, "RGB").show()

a = np.array([[[255, 0, 0], [0, 255, 0]]])
print("Bad:", a.shape, a, a.dtype)
# (1, 2, 3) [[[255 0 0] [0 255 0]]] uint32
print("Where'd the green pixel go?")
Image.fromarray(a, "RGB").show()

a = np.uint8(a)
print("Fixed:", a.shape, a, a.dtype)
# (1, 2, 3) [[[255 0 0] [0 255 0]]] uint8
print("If the green pixel disappeared, you forgot to cast to uint8.")
Image.fromarray(a, "RGB").show()
# or Image.fromarray(a.astype(np.uint8), "RGB").show()
```

Also beware of single-element tuples needing an extra comma:

```py
>>> a = numpy.array((((255,0,0), (0,255,0), (0,0,255), (255,255,0))), dtype=numpy.uint8); a.shape
(4, 3)
>>> a = numpy.array((((255,0,0), (0,255,0), (0,0,255), (255,255,0)),), dtype=numpy.uint8); a.shape
(1, 4, 3)
```

Answer (score -1):

To revert a 2D array of tuples representing the RGB components back to an image I've used this approach:

```
from PIL import Image
import numpy as np

dt = np.dtype([('x', 'u1'), ('y', 'u1'), ('z', 'u1')])

Image.fromarray(im_arr.astype(dt), 'RGB')
```

where im_arr is your 2D array of RGB tuples.

In my case I've used uint8 ('u1') to represent the R, G, B components; if your image components are of a different type adjust the dtype - need to experiment.

Similar question here: [Show a 2d numpy array where contents are tuples as an image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73382388/show-a-2d-numpy-array-where-contents-are-tuples-as-an-image/74248453#74248453)