# Show a 2d numpy array where contents are tuples as an image

Tags: python, image, numpy, image-processing, numpy-ndarray

I have a 2d (M * N) numpy array, where each cell contains a tuple of length 3. The tuple contains R, G, and B values for each pixel, e.g.

`A[0,0] = (0, 255, 0)`

Is there a way to show this array as an image, possibly without the need to transform it first to a 3d (M * N  *3) array?

Comment: I've added the `image-processing` tag to attract the appropriate SO users, because `image` attracts *"docker image"*, *"HTML image"* and *"disk image"* users.

Comment: What is the purpose of storing in a weird format and then trying to make an image, please? Is there some reason to be unconventional? Also, why do you want to avoid `(M, N, 3)` please? And finally, do you want to make this image in order to view it, or to save it to disk? Thank you.

Comment: Please give some indication of the ranges of M and N.

Comment: asking for recommendations. there is a good selection of well-known libraries that can show your image or write it to a file. do a little research, then pick one. -- please present a [mre]. unclear: is this a 2d numpy array of type `object` (containing tuples), or is this a 3d numpy array?

Comment: @MarkSetchell I received the data as described, and to be honest I found it odd to save image data like that as well. M and N are around 20000 and 15000, respectively. Converting to (M * N *3) is what I naturally went for, using nested for loops which is relatively slow, and I am looking for more efficient way of doing this transformation.

Comment: @ChristophRackwitz It is a 2d numpy array of type object.

Answer (score 2):

Image from PIL should be able to generate a picture from a M*N matrix with RGB as a tuple.

```
from PIL import Image
import numpy as np
matrix = np.array([[(100,100,100),(100,100,100),(100,100,100)],[(100,100,100),(100,255,100),(100,100,100)],[(100,100,100),(100,100,100),(100,100,100)]], dtype=np.uint8)
im = Image.fromarray(matrix, 'RGB')
im.show()
```

Comment: I ran your code and the resulting image is a 3*3 square with red diagonal cells, and green, blue, and black off-diagonal cells.

Comment: I might have been too quick to add my answer. Essentially you should be able to use my code, if you change "matrix" to be the same as your np array.

Comment: @math_enthusiast That's due to the values being uint32 instead of uint8. I've fixed the code.

Answer (score 0):

To revert a 2D array of tuples representing the RGB components back to an image I've used this approach:

```
from PIL import Image
import numpy as np

dt = np.dtype([('R', 'u1'), ('G', 'u1'), ('B', 'u1')])

Image.fromarray(array2D.astype(dt), 'RGB')
```

where `array2D` is my 2D array representing the image.

---

Update: more detailed explanation, speed comparison and discussion here: [Import an image as a 2D array of RGB tuples rather than a 3D array of values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74255463/import-an-image-as-a-2d-array-of-rgb-tuples-rather-than-a-3d-array-of-values)