# Import an image as a 2D array of RGB tuples rather than a 3D array of values

Tags: python, image, numpy, image-processing, numpy-ndarray

Is there a NumPy function or "way" to directly import an image as a 2D array of RGB 3-tuples instead of the usual 3D array of values?

So far, I've arrived at this solution:

```
from PIL import Image
import numpy as np

dt = np.dtype([('R','u1'), ('G','u1'), ('B','u1')])

img_in_2D_array = np.asarray(img, dtype='u1').view(dtype=dt).squeeze()
```

but I assume I have missed some easier way e.g. using parameters to some function/method. Please advise.

The reason I want to represent an image as a 2D array of tuples is I'd like to manipulate the RGB values, e.g. reduce the color image to a b/w image (I know this particular one can be done via the `np.average()` method but more complicated operations maybe not that easily).

The result in my example would be:

```
img_in_2D_array.shape  # returns (375, 500)
img_in_2D_array[0,0]  # returns (58, 76, 28)
```

I can print the image using:

```
Image.fromarray(img_in_2D_array.astype(dt), 'RGB')
```

Note: I tried using `np.apply_along_axis()` on the 3D array representing the image but this approach seemed to be noticeably slower than the 2D approach.

---

This is an update after some research and the discussion in the comments:

I've realized `img_in_2D_array` above is NOT a new array but just a view of the existing 3D array. The view "behaves" like an array of tuples but in the memory it's still the original 3D array. So, memory is no concern here.

Let me rephrase my example a bit and show basic properties of the "2D array":

```
from PIL import Image
import numpy as np

arr3D = np.asarray(img, dtype=np.uint8)

dt = np.dtype([('R', 'u1'), ('G', 'u1'), ('B', 'u1')])

arr2D = arr3D.view(dtype=dt).squeeze()

arr2D.base is arr3D  # ---> returns True, so it's a view

arr2D[0,0]  # ---> returns (58, 76, 28), so it "looks like" a tuple

type(arr2D[0,0]) # ---> returns numpy.void, so it's definitely not a physical tuple

arr2D.shape  # ---> returns (375, 500), so it "looks like" a 2D array

arr2D.ndim  # ---> returns 2

arr2D.nbytes  # ---> returns 562500, which equals arr3D.nbytes
```

Now, what this approach brings to me is a convenient (and fast) way to apply vectorized functions:

```
@np.vectorize
def Y(args):
    R, G, B = args
    return 0.299 * R + 0.587 * G + 0.114 * B

grey = Y(arr2D)

Image.fromarray(grey.astype('u1'), 'L')
```

I don't know how to apply function Y directly to arr3D other than using `np.apply_along_axis` but as Cris noted in the comments it just hides a loop and hence it's slow; try this (note unlike the previous example you have to use a plain version of Y, not vectorized):

```
def Y(args):
    R, G, B = args
    return 0.299 * R + 0.587 * G + 0.114 * B

grey = np.apply_along_axis(Y, 2, arr3D)

Image.fromarray(grey.astype('u1'), 'L')
```

It works the same but slower (4 times time in my case).

I think the main advantage of having a 2D view is I can easily apply any function Y working over the RGB components. Indeed, I may have missed something obvious; I'm learning and I'm on a very thin ice here.

If you feel I'm wrong, please let me know where; at the moment the question is closed as duplicate so I can't post this as an answer. I'd close the question but not as a duplicate.

Many thanks for the discussion and valuable comments.

---

This is another update after Cris's great comments. I've compared the execution for all ways to convert a color image to greyscale I could think of and here are the results for 100 repetitions (image (375, 500), uint8, older intel i5, Win10):

#1: 0.40 - 0.50 s

```
grey = arr3D @ [0.299, 0.587, 0.114]
```

#2: 0.50 - 0.70 s

```
grey = arr3D[:,:,0]*0.299 + arr3D[:,:,1]*0.587 + arr3D[:,:,2]*0.114
```

#3: 0.95 - 1.05 s

```
grey = (arr3D * [0.299, 0.587, 0.114]).sum(axis=2)
```

#4: 1.0 - 1.10 s

```
grey = np.average(image, weights=[0.299, 0.587, 0.114], axis=2)
```

#5: 14 - 15 s

```
grey = Y(arr2D)  # see Y and arr2D defined above
```

#6: ~300 s

```
grey = np.apply_along_axis(Y, 2, arr3D)  # see Y defined above
```

As you can see, this confirms Cris's recommendation to avoid `@np.vectorize`, let alone `np.apply_along_axis`, if speed matters :) Interestingly, `np.average` and `.sum` are twice slower than matrix product or direct array adding/multiplication.

Thanks to @CrisLuengo for directing my attention.

---

For the sake of completeness here's a loop solution:

#7: ~225 s

```
grey = loopY(arr3D)
```

where `loopY` is defined:

```
def loopY(image):
    res = np.empty(image.shape[:-1])
    for i in range(image.shape[0]):
        for j in range(image.shape[1]):
            res[i, j] = Y(image[i, j])

    return res
```

So, using `np.apply_along_axis` is the slowest solution, beaten even by a loop :)

Comment: "usual 3D array of values" -- what's the problem with that? `img[0,0]` returns a numpy array (a view) with 3 elements. You can index it the same way as a tuple, and if really necessary can simply cast it to one (but that will have some extra overhead). Also, a 2d array of python tuples would use way more memory, and be significantly slower to handle, since you no longer have a nice flat array of bytes underneath.

Comment: “but more complicated operations maybe not that easily” — In fact, all operations will be easier on a 3D numeric array than on a 2D array of tuples, for the very simple reason that NumPy is optimized to work on numeric arrays. I cannot imagine a single operation that will be easier, or more efficient, on an array of tuples. Don’t do this!

Comment: I'm just trying to find my way around and find the most efficient ways. I tried using `np.apply_along_axis()` to play around with the RGB values but it turns out applying the same operation on the 2D array of RGB tuples runs noticeably faster for the 2D (unless I'm doing something not right). Fair point about memory.

Comment: Why don’t you ask that question then? `apply_along_axis` just hides a loop that repeatedly calls some Python function. Your operation can most surely be vectorized, needing no loops at all.

Comment: Thanks @CrisLuengo, I'll investigate further and post the results. However, I'm still interested in knowing whether an image can be imported as a 2D array directly, even if only useful as an exercise.

Comment: I don’t know any package that deals with images as arrays of tuples, so the answer most likely is that there is no way to import images directly in that form. In Python you can read in images through imageio, PIL/Pillow, OpenCV, DIPlib, and matplotlib. All of these represent color images as a 3D array, or some other form of contiguous buffer. Likely there are other similar packages I’m not aware of, so I can’t give an absolute answer. There are also file format specific packages, the ones I know also use a single contiguous buffer. Note that an array of tuples is not a contiguous buffer.

Comment: The reason I’m comfortable telling you it can’t be done is precisely that: an array of tuples is not a contiguous buffer, and therefore highly inefficient. No package would offer data in such an inefficient way. If such a package exists, I wouldn’t trust it to be good code.

Comment: As Cris says. Just for illustration -- your image of 500x375 takes something under 600 KiB raw, as a flat byte array. For an array of tuples, you have (on 64bit) ~1.5 MiB of pointers, and then each tuple object is 72 bytes (by my observation) -- that's another ~13.5 MiB of individually allocated tuple objects. That's 26x more memory usage, with each access requiring an indirection.

Comment: Many thanks @CrisLuego and DanMašek, I take it as a great answer to my question and a direction in my further exploring the arrays. I will doublecheck my initial observation regarding the speed and post verifiable examples (unless I was wrong). Thanks again.

Comment: @CrisLuengo, DanMašek: it turns out memory is of no concern here because the 2D array of tuples I'm working with is not a new physical array but just a view of the 3D with a different dtype (which I haven't realized initially). This explains why my operations over the 2D array are fast - because they are in fact operations over the original 3D structure (by operations I mean vectorized functions). Viewing the 3D array as a 2D array of RGB tuples helps me to learn to work with the images but you may be right it's not at all necessary (with more experience). Thanks again for your input!

Comment: @CrisLuengo, I've just updated the question text with more examples; I don't know the insides but the 2D view I'm talking about just looks and behaves like a 2D array of tuples but internally remains a 3D array of values. Please review whether the new examples make sense to you. I can't address your concerns above due to my lack of experience unfortunately.

Comment: @isCzech So it is possible. I stand corrected! However, 100 repetitions of `Y(arr2D)` takes 3.25 s on my machine, whereas 100 repetitions of `img[:,:,0]*0.299 + img[:,:,1]*0.587 + img[:,:,2]*0.114` takes 0.093 s. This latter is the vectorized version of the operation. (`@np.vectorize` makes the function applicable to an array, but it still iterates over the array behind the scenes. Actual vectorization prevents Python from looping at all, the loops are in compiled NumPy code, orders of magnitude faster.)

Comment: Or rather, the difference is between applying a Python function to each element of an array, versus calling NumPy functions that work on the array as a whole. You can do the same computation using a matrix product: `img @ [0.299, 0.587, 0.114]`. This is actually a little slower, it takes 0.127 s to do 100 repetitions on my machine. In short, don't use `np.apply_along_axis()` or `@np.vectorize` unless there really is no other option.

Comment: @CrisLuengo, thanks for your comments, I've posted my comparison of the same image conversion confirming your observation indeed.